# Replace column name with matching value in seperate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Task description**

I have `df` and `df1` and wish to make `df` column names who are in the column `country` in `df1` be changed to the string in `loc`. E.g. Australia become AU. The final output would be `df2`. Any help would be super!!

**DataFrames**

`df`

```
  Date       Argentina  Australia United Kingdom  United States
1983-03-31     0.001   0.053206       0.001       0.160159
1983-04-30     0.001   0.053206       0.001       0.160159
1983-05-31     0.001   0.053206       0.001       0.160159
```

`df1`

```
country           loc
Argentina          AR
Australia          AU
United Kingdom     GB
United States      US
```

**Final desired output**

`df2`

```
 Date            AR        AU      UK       US
1983-03-31     0.001   0.053206  0.001  0.160159
1983-04-30     0.001   0.053206  0.001  0.160159
1983-05-31     0.001   0.053206  0.001  0.160159
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.rename`:

```
new_df = df.rename(columns=df2.set_index("country")["loc"])
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
         Date     AR        AU     GB        US
0  1983-03-31  0.001  0.053206  0.001  0.160159
1  1983-04-30  0.001  0.053206  0.001  0.160159
2  1983-05-31  0.001  0.053206  0.001  0.160159
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight different approach, also with `rename` but creating a `dictionary` for name conversion:

```
df2 = df.rename(columns=df1['loc'].to_dict())
```

Yielding:

```
         Date     AU        AR      GB        US
0  1983-03-31  0.001  0.053206   0.001  0.160159
1  1983-04-30  0.001  0.053206   0.001  0.160159
2  1983-05-31  0.001  0.053206   0.001  0.160159
```